# Why is it not possible to have multiple arguments for single condition in if-statement?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, theory

Why do no languages allow for multiple arguments for a single if-statement condition? Why can I do `if (x == true) {...}`, but I can't do `if (x,y,z == true) {...}`? I understand that some posts say you can get around this problem with a switch statement, but I want to know why it's not possible to use an if-statement. I want to know the theory behind it. Is it just because nobody has added it to there language's syntax? Is it prevented by the compiler or something similar?

Comment: I've wondered this myself. In PHP, you could get similar markup using `in_array`; e.g `in_array(false, [true, true, false])` would return `true` because it contains `false`. Or, if you want to execute only if everything is true, you could do `!in_array(false, [true, true, false])`

Comment: Probably because languages eventually translate into machine code. Any operation which compared three values to ensure each of them is true would consist of at least five operations. A logical expression with that syntax `a,b = true` would be expanded into two commands `a == true && b == true`, which would execute as three machine instructions. A language syntax could implement the logic, but apparently it just hasn't seemed important.

Comment: @the_storyteller the same would be applied to switch statements when they get turned into machine code, but you can still do `case x: case y: [code] break;`

Comment: In an if statement, a developer wanting to see if all three values were true probably wouldn't use an `== true` with each value. Instead, they'd probably just say `if (a && b && c) { /* code */ }`. It translates to less instructions (although a good compiler should perform similar optimizations.) In the end, it's purely a matter of what the makers of the language chose to implement, so there isn't really a "right" answer.